# How can i read texfile line by line and add to array using C#

Tags: c#, api, sms

Am using [AfricasTalking](https://github.com/AfricasTalkingLtd/africastalking.Net) C# class to send Airtime. First you create and array of numbers to send airtime. Below is a code to create Arraylist. Instead i want to read numbers from a text file and add to rec1.

```
ArrayList AirtimeRecipientsList = new ArrayList();

// Declare hashtable to hold the first number
// Please ensure you include the country code for phone numbers (+254 for Kenya in this case)
// Please ensure you include the country code for phone numbers (KES for Kenya in this case)
// Specify the country currency and the amount as shown below

Hashtable rec1 = new Hashtable();
rec1["phoneNumber"] = txtPhoneNo.Text;
rec1["amount"] = "KES "+ txtAmount.Text;

// Add recipient to list
AirtimeRecipientsList.Add(rec1);

// Declare hashtable to hold the another number
//Hashtable rec2 = new Hashtable();
//rec2["phoneNumber"] = "+254733YYYZZZ";
//rec2["amount"] = "KES XXX";

// Add recipient to list
//AirtimeRecipientsList.Add(rec2);`
```

Comment: `foreach(var item in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path)` is your friend. And I think you could use a class/struct instead of hashtables to store recipients' data.

Comment: and [TextFieldParser Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) is your friend as well. Note: It is in the  `Microsoft.VisualBasic` but can perfectly be used in C# with no inconvinients.

Comment: Thanks Olivier for that quick response, if you don't mind can I see a sample code, I will really appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your text file has phone number and amount separated by comma or any character like this "123456789, KES 500" on each line without quotes.
Here is some code.

```
    var recipients = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(path to text file);
    ArrayList recipientsList = new ArrayList();
     foreach(var line in recipients)
         { 
           Hashtable rec1 = new Hashtable();
          rec1["phoneNumber"] = line.Split(',')[0];
          rec1["amount"] = line.Split(',')[1];
           recipientsList.Add(rec1)
         }
```

That's it.